# Automatic hashing of passwords in TypeORM + NestJS application during user model persistence

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decorator, typeorm

How can I automatically set the hashed password column in a TypeORM + NestJS application when saving a user model? I have a user model with a `password` property and a corresponding hashed password column in the database. I want to only set the value of the `password` field, and have the hashed password automatically generated and saved to the database.

I have researched using listeners like `@BeforeInsert()`, but it seems that these listeners are not triggered when using the `insert()` method. Are there any alternative approaches or solutions to handle this requirement?

Comment: What do you want to do with the instance? Notice that the decorator runs only once when the class is created. You'd need to create an initialiser or something that runs on every instance.

Comment: Oh thank you, I just wanna do something like change my property's value. So seem like decorator will not help...

Comment: Change how and when?

Comment: Like when save a model, my property get value from another property.

Comment: Why not just use a getter/setter for that?

Comment: But the property's value need to save to database...

Comment: What database? Please tell us about your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: My User model uses TypeORM and NestJS. It has password property and hashed password column property. I want to be able to set a new user with a raw password, but only the hashed password value should be saved to the database automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated assistance. I am new bie.

Comment: Should I create another question, and I close this question?

Comment: You can just [edit] it

Comment: Consider using a setter, constructor, or factory method for creating new users with plain passwords (or just call the `changePassword` method that you'll need anyway). But the `.password` should not actually be part of the model, you should only ever need/use/store the password hash!

Comment: When working with Ruby on Rails, I noticed that the "password" property is a part of my Model, and it can be easily saved.

Answer (score 0):

try put it in your entity

```
  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    if (this.password) {
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But it seems that these listeners are not triggered when using the insert() method...

Comment: can you provide your querybuilder?

Comment: `
.createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(User)
      .values([
        { username: ..., password: ... },
        { username: ..., password: ... },
      ])
`

Comment: i think you should use 
const user = User.create({...your_dto}); 
and then
user.save();